# SSRS display top n but have SUM include all values

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I currently have a tabllix in SSRS with multiple rows, but I wish to only display the top 5 rows, yet have the total column at the bottom include the values for however many rows are in the table.

Example:

```
NameID    /   Sales  /   % of Total
1         /    100    /
4         /    70    /
3        /     65    /
2        /     50   /
7        /     35    /
```

---

```
DO NOT DISPLAY THESE RECORDS:
6        /     25    /
5        /     10    /
```

---

```
TOTAL SALES:   355   (inclusive of all 7 records)
```

I need this total sales number to be accurate so that I can then use it for the % of Total column.

I don't believe a filter for top n on the dataset will work because that will not include the lower records in the dataset.

The only thing I can think to do is to make the row visibility so it only displays the first 5 rows, except I do not know how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rownumber column to your query (SQL)

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY FIeldName1 ORDER BY FieldName1 Asc) AS rownum

On the Report:

- Right click on any Tablix column and select Tablix Properties
- Click on Filters

Expression: rownum

Operator: <

Value: 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use Top N to do this.
Look '[How to get total of top 10 sales in SSRS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275232/how-to-get-total-of-top-10-sales-in-ssrs)'