# SSRS Tablix - Total with Top N

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I made a Tablix with Row and Column grouping that filters for the **Top 10** highest. I also need **Totals** but it is totaling all of the records and of course I just want the total for the **Top 10** ones in the table.

I tried using RunningValue but it doesn't reset with each Column Group.

[How to get total of top 10 sales in SSRS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275232/how-to-get-total-of-top-10-sales-in-ssrs-2012)

Is there a way to only total the Top 10? I use the Dataset for other tables and charts so I'd rather not make separate ones (especially since I need the same functionality on other tables).

[image]

Comment: What expression are you using for your RunningValue calculation?

Comment: I was using =RunningValue(Fields!Yourdatafield.Value,sum,"CLAIM_TYPE") . I finally gave up and used an array in code to do what I needed.