# Total SUM in SSRS doesnt display corrent number

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sum

The reason for that probably lays in my query, because I used `MAX` to pick up the unique record. 
But now my SSRS report does not display correct `NetWrittenPremium` amount. 
What would be a workaround for this problem?
[image]
Here is my query:

```
select  b.YearNum,
        b.MonthNum,
        ClassCode,
        QLL.Description,
        SUM( Premium) as NetWrittenPremium
FROM        tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics prm ON b.MonthNum=Month(prm.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum = YEAR(EffectiveDate)  
AND prm.EffectiveDate >=DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) AND prm.EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE())  AND CompanyLine = 'Ironshore Insurance Company' 
LEFT JOIN  NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote Q ON prm.NetRate_QuoteID = Q.QuoteID
LEFT JOIN NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat QL ON Q.QuoteID = QL.QuoteID  

LEFT JOIN   (SELECT * FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi nqI 
            JOIN ( SELECT LocationID as LocID, MAX(ClassCode) as ClCode 
            FROM NetRate_Quote_Insur_Quote_Locat_Liabi  GROUP BY LocationID ) nqA 
            ON nqA.LocID = nqI.LocationID AND nqA.ClCode = nqI.ClassCode ) QLL 
            ON QLL.LocationID = QL.LocationID 

WHERE ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) ) 
GROUP BY b.YearNum,b.MonthNum,ClassCode,        QLL.Description
```

My tablix structure:I am gruping on Description and ClassCode.Sorting it by `SUM(NetWrittenPremium) DESC` and Filtering by `SUM(NetWrittenPremium) TOP 10`. And another group is MonthNum. 
[image]

[image]

I have added a new group with grouping expression =1
But still same incorrect totals
[image]

Comment: A couple of questions:  Any chance you could give us a look at the tablix structure and groups as well?  And are you doing any static or parameter based filtering?

Comment: Just added some info about my Tablix Structure

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that group filters don't apply to aggregate functions.  So 
your SUM()s are picking everything up.  From the MSDN documentation for Expression Scope for Totals, Aggregates, and Built-in Collections (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256.aspx):

> Group filters are not used when calculating aggregates for data
>   regions.

If possible, it is probably best to move the Top 10 statement into the query instead.

If that's not an option, you should be able to use your "Rank" expression instead.  Create a "totaling" row at the detail level that counts up running dollar values using RunningValue.  Then set the visibility criteria to:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ClassCode.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) <> 10
```

**Edit:** Apparently there is an MSDN thread that covers this scenario.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0b21bab0-ff02-4655-a69c-efedfb2a7077.

Comment: Here is the expression In Total row, NetWrittenPremiumCell    `=RunningValue(Fields!NetWrittenPremium.Value,SUM,"DataSet1")`
Is that Correct?
But then, I dont have column Rank in my query, how can I hide this visibility?

Comment: In doing a quick check, I found an MSDN thread and linked it above for reference.  I also amended the answer to include the cleaner visibility expression that I saw there.

Comment: Hey Bitnine, do you know is any other way to contact those people from Social.msdn.com?
I really need to resolve this problem. 
BTW, thank you for your time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that your group is filtering for the **top 10** but the Total line isn't.

Add a new group **Add Group -> Adjacent Below** for your total line. Group it on 1 (so it groups them all together). Then use the same expressions as you used for the other cells (add a SUM if they aren't already). Add the same **TOP 10 Filter** to the new group.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am filtering for TOP 10 but total calculates for all values. 
I added new group. In a group expression I said `=1`, applied filter expression: `SUM(NetWrittenPremium) = TOP 10`
But it still gives me the same incorrect  totals.
Am I missing something?