# How can I create a parameter which choosing a number of top of values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I've created a report in SSRS 2008. The report contains fields: Number of requests, Organization of the initiator

How can I create a parameter which choosing a number of top of values from field Number of requests

Example, set value of parameter 5:

```
Number of requests, Organization of the initiator    
10                  initiator1    
9                   initiator2    
8                   initiator3    
7                   initiator4    
6                   initiator5
```

Comment: Can you edit your questions to include the SQL for your main dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this. You can either do the work in the report as in this similar question [How to get total of top 10 sales in SSRS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275232/how-to-get-total-of-top-10-sales-in-ssrs-2012)

Or you can do this in your dataset. Assuming you are using SQL Server you can do something like this.

```
-- declare @TopN int = 5 -- Comment this out in production this is only used for testing. This parameter will be passed in from SSRS

SELECT * FROM
    (
    select NumberOfRequests, Organization
        , RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NumberOfRequests desc) as rnk
    from MyTable
    ) q
    WHERE q.rnk <= @TopN
```

All we are doing here is selecting the data assigning each row a rank based on NumberOfRequests, biggest = 1 next biggest = 2 etc.....

Then we have have an outer query that simply selects anything where the rank is less than your desired number.