# SSRS Report - Reporting Services RDLC

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I'm trying to make a report, put only 3 indicators in my report, the 3 highest values ​​in the whole column. I have tried several solutions but I still do not get it.

[This is the example, the left column is how I can do it, but I need only the 3 highest ones as I will show later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wo5G.png)

[that's how I'd like to show it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r7X1.png)

If someone could tell me how to do it, I would appreciate your help

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the underlying query using TOP and ORDER BY:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    [FirstValue],
    [SecondValue]
FROM [YourTable]
ORDER BY [FirstValue] ;
```

If you can't alter the query, you can try adding a row number in SSRS and then hide any rows where the row number > 3. See this post: 
[how-to-get-total-of-top-10-sales-in-ssrs-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275232/how-to-get-total-of-top-10-sales-in-ssrs-2012).

Comment: in the query I can not send it, it has to be directly in the report. Is there any way?